# Swagger query strings in path not allowed

Tags: swagger

Can someone explain me why I have an error

> Query string in path are not allowed

I use OpenApi 3.0.1 and I follow this documentation where this part of code is described. So this errors should not appear but it is, why?

```
/posts/{postid}?offset=0&limit=5:
get:
  tags:
  - posts
  summary: example
  description: 'example text'
  operationId: getComments
  parameters:
  - name: postId
    in: path
    description: Post id
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string
  - name: offset
    in: query
    schema:
      type: integer
    description: The number of items to skip before starting to collect the result set
    required: false
  - in: query
    name: limit
    schema:
      type: integer
    description: The numbers of items to return
    required: false
  responses:
    200:
      description: example desc
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResponseData'
    422:
      description: Unprocessable entity
      content: {}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should write:

`/posts/{postid}`

instead of

`/posts/{postid}?offset=0&limit=5:`

The definitions of offset and limit in parameters section are enough to know these are query parameters since they already contain property `in: query`.

If you look at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/, it is not said you should add the query string as is in the paths section of the swagger specification. (What may be confusing is that some GET requests containing a query string are shown, which may confuse you in believing you should write the query string as is in swagger specification.)